# Sort array by date - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I want to sort an array of objects by date, but the problem is their date is in this format - `2014-07-17T13:49:12.767Z`.

Here an example of one object in this array

```
{
  id: 578,
  creationDate: "2014-07-16T20:56:04.710Z",
  creationUser: "FCOUT",
  modificationDate: "2014-07-17T13:49:12.767Z",
  modificationUser: "FCOUT",
  name: "Regra Filipe",
  description: "Teste",
  type: "Message",
  regulation: null,
  structure: 1,
  deleted: false,
}
```

I have to sort them by modification date or creation date!

Comment: Why is it a problem that the dates are in UTC format? Doesn't that make things easier? Just use a normal sort: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: What exactly makes you think that the date format is a problem? Did you even try anything?

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759127/2247494)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write a sort function as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript). In your case the compare function will just be comparing two strings , which in the date format you have mentioned should work out of the box.

ie you can compare the two dates as strings.

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla sorting documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

use the compare function

```
function(a, b) {
    if (a.creationDate < b.creationDate) { return -1; }
    if (a.creationDate > b.creationDate) { return 1; }
    return 0;
}
```

Your date format allows the creationDate strings to just be compared lexicographically